With respect to Juniper MXs, how does flexible vlan tagging differ from encapsulation extended vlan bridge?
Can anyone please explain the difference between flexible vlan tagging and encapsulation 'extended vlan-bridge'?
Does setting the encapsulation 'extended vlan-bridge' put all sub interfaces into family bridge automatically?

encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge: it applies the vlan-bridge encapsulation to all the units, so it can be used when you have single- or double-tagged units
encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services: it allows you to specify different per-unit encapsulation. In this way you can have some units which do bridging with vlan-bridge encapsulation, some layer-3 units and some units that do VPLS bridging with vlan-vpls encapsulation.

How does it differs from flexible vlan tagging?
